# Why is the "edit" option for questions not available?

Tags: support

I just noticed this today, and it is only on the Android Enthusiasts site. The "edit" option for questions is not clickable.

[image]

This "edit" for questions was active before today. The "edit" option on answers and comments is still accessible. Why would the "edit" option for questions be disabled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It is not a bug, It is a design feature

I came across the same thing yesterday. Apparently it was because the **"Suggested Edit" queue was full**.

Now as some of the posts in suggested queue was reviewed by members with more than 2K reputation, edit button can be accessed again.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Also, see related post [Tell us when the suggested edit queue is full/busy on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134220/tell-us-when-the-suggested-edit-queue-is-full-busy-on-stackoverflow) and [Cannot make suggested edits on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134216/cannot-make-suggested-edits-on-stackoverflow/134217)

Comment: Hmm, that reminds me that I'm skipping more than Approving or Improving.

Comment: Ah- this makes sense! It looks like more of us on AE need to get to 2K reputation to help out. I do agree with that [SO meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134220/tell-us-when-the-suggested-edit-queue-is-full-busy-on-stackoverflow) that there should be a better sign that the queue is full other than just disabling the "edit" option. Thanks!

Comment: This is new to me! Meanwhile, it seems that [the current capacity is 160](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98882/241919) (possibly 200 on SO due to its activity).